# I'm not getting the original URL Based Android

Tags: java, android

After creating a separate thread on Android, they try to get a original URL. Through the short URL.
But I didn't get it - sorry not native english.

My code:

```
public class Expander_URL{

  private String expandURL="";
  private URL url;


  public String Expand(String short_url)throws IOException {
    url = new URL(short_url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

    this.expandURL = conn.getHeaderField("Location");
    conn.disconnect();

    return this.expandURL;
  }

}
```

Comment: You should check what `getResponseCode()` returns.

Comment: i got response code 0

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Zero is not a valid response code.